# Resource not found for the segment 'siteCollections'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to download documents attached to a OneNote Page using the Microsoft Graph API.

I find attached documents by looking for `<object>` elements like this in the document:-

```
<object data-attachment="test.txt" type="text/plain" data="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/siteCollections/contoso.sharepoint.com,eb44cb06-54aa-4c1b-b749-14a6bc939040,90c50fc9-e9d8-483c-817d-a6006510e8e8/onenote/resources/1-11dbf2c6ff9e32c6a479858c38ac4688!1-c256504c-f305-4df3-9d00-f6d72aef06fc/$value"></object>
```

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-input-output-html#output-html-example-for-objects) the `data` attribute is the URL to the file. I make a `GET` request to that url, replacing `$value` in the URL with `content` according to how files are downloaded as binary as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resource-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), authorizing my request with the token.

When I perform this request, I get HTTP Code `400` and the following in the body:-

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'siteCollections'.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-14T12:32:04",
      "request-id": "6b7a9242-8cc0-4df5-afb6-075735045d0d"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `/siteCollections/` with `/sites/` in the URL produced a URL that yielded a successful response.

Weird quirk of OneNote?

Comment: Correct, /sites is the appropriate path for SharePoint items.  If run into additional problems feel free to follow up or open a new item.